# Server socket.io on('connection') callback not being called

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, socket.io, digital-ocean

I'm using Socket.io to connect a Digital Ocean Node.js server to an iOS Swift app. I've been using the same code with ngrok to build the app and I'm just now switching to Digital Ocean.

The connection event is happening because the Swift app is going through its checks that occur with a connect event (i.e., trying to pull data).  However, the callback on the server is not being called so none of the listeners on the server are being called.

I'm doing a regular instantiation of SocketIOClient without any additional parameters:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "https://my_domain.com")!)
```

The connection function on the server looks like this:

```
socket.on("connect") {data, ack in }
```

I have the following server dependencies:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var listeners = require('./listeners');
var bson = require('bson')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var apn = require('apn');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var querystring = require('querystring');
```

The connection function on the server looks like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("connected")
})
```

The issue is that nothing is getting printed or happening on the server.  The listener is within `MongoClient.connect` but Mongo is connecting successfully and items are printing within that function, so things are just stopping with the `on('connection')` function.

Again this was working fine on ngrok.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you started the server on any port ?? server.listen(3000);

Comment: Your code shows an `http` server on the server-end of things and it shows an `https` URL on the client-end of things.  Those must match.  Also, what port are you starting the server on?

Comment: The server is listening on 8080.  Again, other things are happening on both client and server to prove that the server is listening and a connection is being made.  I changed it to https and the client response stopped whereas there had been a client response with just http.